# Alt gets stuck leaving the teamviewer window with Alt+Tab

Tags: teamviewer

I use Teamviewer on Ubuntu (Not sure if the problem is the same on Windows).

Whenever I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to change the focussed window on my computer to another window while the remote window has focus
the remote window catches the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keydown event **but not the <kbd>Alt</kbd> release event!** So when I get back to the remote Teamviewer window the remote computer still has the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key stuck pressed.

How can I prevent that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key gets stuck on the remote computer?

Comment: Yes, in Windows, stuck keys happen in many or most  RDP / VNC situations.  Some programs are worse than others in triggering this.  My suggested fix by the DEVs is to alert us in the UI when these keys are supposedly depressed, so we know when they are depressed.  Likewise, you can lock your mouse into a mode where it thinks that you are holding down the left click, and appear to be dragging something... Good luck on letting go, if you haven't pressed left-click!

Comment: Currently struggling with this when connecting to Ubuntu 18.04 with TeamViewer 14.2.8352 and then with 14.7.1965 running on macOS 10.13.3. Regardless of **Send key combinations** yes/no. Not even doing Alt+TAB, just whenever typing too fast or maybe typing too soon after saving the file with Ctrl+S. So frustrating, only reconnect helps and not for long.

Answer (score 8):

[This creatively titled TeamViewer support thread](http://teamviewerforums.com/index.php?topic=1729.0) discusses this problem, and unfortunately the response from TeamViewer was "cannot reproduce."

> Thank you for your patience.
>
> We have received word from our QA team. They advised that the issue was not able to be reproduced, using several different models / brands of keyboards.

Even though that thread is for Windows, some of the workarounds discussed are system agnostic, and should be faster than using CompizConfig.

1. In the TeamViewer remote window, try mashing the modifier keys <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. In the TeamViewer remote window controls, disable and re-enable the **Send key combinations** option

In my experience, option 1 works to release a stuck key.

Comment: I got the issue. They could try having a mac with OSX Versión 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2) like mine, taking a windows on the other giving screen.

Comment: I got it happen to me today on a Chromebook, with the winkey getting stuck somehow? Nothing I did would fix it. Furthermore, the ChromeApp version doesn't have "send key combinations"...

Comment: It seems everyone has the issue except their QA team...even 5 years later

Comment: Mashing actually seems to help sometimes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the same problem.

Here is a **workaround** I have found:

1. install CompizConfig Settings Manager via Ubuntu software center
2. Locate the unity plugin inside the CompizConfig Settings Manager
3. From the switcher tab disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination while using Teamviewer
4. undo this setting when you are finished using Teamviewer.

Comment: You can use AutoHotkey on windows to achieve the same thing - disable Alt tab

Answer (score 1):

It's 2020 now and this is still an issue. I see it multiple times in a short period because I am remoting from a Windows 10 machine using Google Chrome to connect) to another Windows 10 machine and use a lot of Windows shortcut keys.

If I press Alt+Tab (which I do often), the Alt key gets stuck on every single time.

Similarly, if I press a Ctrl key combination (e.g., Ctrl+A for Select All), I often see the Ctrl key get stuck, and the same when using a Windows key combination (e.g., Win+E to open Windows Explorer), which causes the Windows key to get stuck.

While this is extremely annoying and I try to avoid the Windows shortcut keys that cause this when remotely connected, it's habit, and I often have Alt, Ctrl or the Windows key stuck. When this happens, all sorts of unexpected behaviors begin, such as not being able to type text into apps, Windows opening unexpectedly, etc.

I HAVE FOUND A WAY TO GET THE KEYS UNSTUCK

Steps:

1. Use the MOUSE to open Windows Explorer
2. Navigate to any folder with files in it
3. Press and hold the offending "stuck" key (e.g., press and hold the Alt key)
4. While pressing and holding the "stuck" key, double-click a file or folder
5. Close any window that might open (if no window opens, double-click the file or folder again)
6. Repeat steps 3-5 with any other "stuck" key...9 times out of 10 this clears the stuck key
7. If steps 1-6 didn't unstick the stuck key, disconnect and reconnect to the remote computer. This 7th step will clear the stuck key if steps 1-6 didn't
8. If steps 1-7 didn't unstick the stuck key, reboot the remote computer...this is a guaranteed fix, but steps 1-6 or steps 1-7 usually work and prevent you from having to reboot the remote computer